# How to stream video, with MediaElement, from a database, in chunks

Tags: silverlight, sql-server-2008, mediaelement

I have a `MediaElement` that plays video. I have my video stored, in binary, in my SQL Server database.

The way this works out for me is that the Silverlight app reads ALL the binary data from a web service. The web service returns a `byte[]` that I turn into a stream, and set as source for the `MediaElement`.

The big problem with this is that it needs to read all the data before the `MediaElement`'s source can be set. With large videos, this takes a long time.

So, I was hoping to somehow take chunks, and buffer as I go, like any online video player does.

Any clues on how I can actually do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this a bit different. 
I couldn't figure out buffering from the DB, so we setup a mediaserver, and used the silverlight app, to stream from that instead.

Comment: Hi<br>
Could you please explain what did you do ? Because I have a similar problem.<br>
There are a lot of films on a server which clients should watch them via Silverlight's MediaElement.

Is that possible to have a MediaElement like :

    <MediaElement Source="mms://server/album/film1.wmv"></MediaElement>

The problem is that we don't want to have the whole film being burst into the client.

I have tested **Mezzmo** and **IIS Live Smooth Streaming** but I can't find the mms addresses which they represent their content.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this article](http://forums.silverlight.net/p/227000/551069.aspx) on the Silverlight Forums, which has a similar question (audio instead of video).

The solution states:
*"You can try to create a ASX file to hold the playlist and set the ASX file as the source of the MediaElement."*

One of the links provided in the solution goes on to say:
*"An ASX file is simply an XML file that specifies the media files in the playlist.  Playlists provide, among other things, a central entry point for a group of media."*

It sounds like you should be able set the source of your `MediaElement` to a `Silverlight Playlist`, or `ASX File`, and then download your video, in chunks (possibly as separate "files"), to that `Playlist`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: But this needs files placed somewhere, if I understand correctly. I have it stored in a DB.

Comment: Hmm.. I wonder if it would be possible to store other MediaElement objects within a Silverlight Playlist? Then maybe you could create the MediaElement objects dynamically as you download your video from the DB? Then still have your "main" MediaElement reference the Playlist? Just a shot in the dark... I haven't done this before.